# save data in an array with php, and that array save it in session,and every time I reload the page it shows the saved data and the new data entered

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
    require "GuardarSesion.php";
    $arreglo = new Arreglo();
    $arreglo -> agregar(67);
    $arreglo -> guardarSesion();
    var_dump($arreglo -> leerSesion()); 
?> 
<?php
    class Arreglo
    {
        private $miArreglo = array();

        function agregar($dato)
        {                                  
                $id+=1;
                array_push($this->miArreglo,$id, $dato);                           
        }
        function guardarSesion()
        {            
            session_start(); 
            $_SESSION['MiArreglo'] = $this->miArreglo;  
        }
        function leerSesion()
        {            
            session_start();
            return $_SESSION['MiArreglo'];
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: I can not make it show me the data before entered, just update the array, and I want to show me what I enter and the new ones :/

Comment: SHow us what is in `GuardarSesion.php`

Comment: But as a General Rule. Start the session once right at the beginning of the script and make sure you do it before you send anything to the browser i.e. an echo or even a single piece of HTML

Answer (score -1):

Your question is unclear, but according to my assumption you want to show the previous stored data and also the new one.

In your **function agregar($dato)** you are pushing data into **$this->miArreglo** which doesn't contain previous data. You need to push data into the **$_SESSION['MiArreglo']** array.

Here's the code:

```
function agregar($dato)
{
    $id+=1;
    array_push($_SESSION['MiArreglo'],$id, $dato);
}
```

It is also unclear from your code that what **$id** variable already contains, as you are adding **$id+=1;**